# Using xarray with resample and interpolate to animate the movement of contours

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, python-xarray

Lets say I have the following python code, showing a contour value at 12pm and 1pm, indicating that it's position has moved:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


%matplotlib widget

ani = None
# Create the data array for the first time point
data_12 = np.zeros((1, 6, 6))  # Creating a 3D array with time dimension (1), and size 6x6
data_12[0, 1, 1] = 6  # Setting the value at 1x1 location to 6

# Create the xarray dataset for the first time point
ds_12 = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "value": (["time", "x", "y"], data_12)
    },
    coords={
        "time": [np.datetime64("2024-01-01T12:00")],
        "x": np.arange(6),
        "y": np.arange(6),
    },
)

# Create the data array for the second time point
data_13 = np.zeros((1, 6, 6))
data_13[0, 0, 0] = 0
data_13[0, 4, 4] = 6
ds_13 = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "value": (["time", "x", "y"], data_13)
    },
    coords={
        "time": [np.datetime64("2024-01-01T13:00")],
        "x": np.arange(6),
        "y": np.arange(6),
    },
)

ds_concat = xr.concat([ds_12, ds_13], dim="time")
ds_interp = ds_concat.resample(time="1min").interpolate("linear")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 5)

data_selected = ds_interp.isel(time=1)
cont = ax.contourf(data_selected["x"], data_selected["y"],data_selected["value"], cmap='viridis')

def animatehere(i):
    global cont
    data_selected = ds_interp.isel(time=i)
    cont = ax.contourf(data_selected["x"], data_selected["y"],data_selected["value"], cmap='viridis')
    return cont

def init():
    pass

ani = FuncAnimation(fig,animatehere,init_func=init, frames=60,interval=30, repeat=False)
ani.save('animation.gif', writer='pillow')
plt.show()
```

This creates the following output.

[image]

I want to know how I can interpolate this data so that it shows the contour moving from point to point rather than it simply disappearing in one location and re-appearing in another. In this example the intensity does not change, it's 6 in one location and 6 in the other but any solution should also be able to handle the intensity changing over time.

Can someone give me an example of how this might work or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Will there be only one object in your ultimate use-case?  With only one object it might be possible to infer that the path between the two observations is continuous and that any intensity change is monotonic.  If there could be multiple objects moving between the timestamps, identifying the pairings and paths is a difficult problem.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment you are interpolating between two images, whereas you want to interpolate the data of which the two images are imperfect representations; specifically, you want to interpolate movement along a path of which you have two image snap-shots.

There are three options:

1. You stay in image space, and define what pixels are background and what pixels are the object of interest. Then you can move the object pixels along the path in image coordinates.
2. You determine the position of the object in data space, interpolate the path, work back to image space.
3. You ditch the image space and make a more compact visualization of the data space.

Option 1 is madness, so I will present solutions for options 2 and 3.

#### Option 2:

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# define a path and object intensity
x = [1, 1, 4, 4, 1]
y = [1, 4, 4, 1, 1]
z = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]

# interpolate path
time = np.linspace(0, 1, len(x))
interpolator = interp1d(time, np.vstack([x, y, z]), kind="linear")
total_frames = 60
interpolated_time = np.linspace(0, 1, total_frames)
xi, yi, zi = interpolator(interpolated_time)

# create meshes
x_range = (0, 5)
y_range = (0, 5)
x_resolution = 10
y_resolution = 10
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(*x_range, x_resolution),
                   np.linspace(*y_range, y_resolution))
shape = X.shape
Z = np.zeros(shape)

# initialize a KD-tree to find the nearest mesh nodes quickly
tree = cKDTree(np.vstack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel())).T)

# initialize figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(z))
ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 5)

def animate(t):
    _, idx = tree.query((xi[t], yi[t]))
    Z = np.zeros(shape)
    Z.ravel()[idx] = zi[t]
    return ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=np.max(z))

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=total_frames, interval=30, repeat=False)
ani.save('animation.gif', writer='pillow')
plt.show()
```

#### Option 3:

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# define a path and object intensity
x = [1, 1, 4, 4, 1]
y = [1, 4, 4, 1, 1]
z = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]

# interpolate path
time = np.linspace(0, 1, len(x))
interpolator = interp1d(time, np.vstack([x, y, z]), kind="linear")
total_frames = 600
interpolated_time = np.linspace(0, 1, total_frames)
xi, yi, zi = interpolator(interpolated_time)

# initialize figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
artist, = ax.plot(xi[0], yi[0], 'o', markersize=20, color=plt.cm.viridis(zi[0]/np.max(z)))
ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 5)

def animate(t):
    artist.set_data(np.atleast_2d(xi[t]), np.atleast_2d(yi[t]))
    artist.set_color(plt.cm.viridis(zi[t]/np.max(z)))
    return artist,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=total_frames, repeat=False, interval=30, blit=True)
ani.save('animation.gif', writer='pillow')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to create a smooth transition that shows intensity dropping on the first point while increasing on the second point.

I switched to using numeric values for the time dimension, which gave me more control over how the data transitions from one point to another. In the animation, I cleared the plot at the start of each frame. Hence, the square contour moves smoothly across the grid.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# Function to create a square-shaped contour
def square_blob(x, y, x0, y0, intensity, size=1):
    return intensity * ((np.abs(x - x0) <= size / 2) & (np.abs(y - y0) <= size / 2))

# Grid
x = np.arange(0, 6, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 6, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)


data_12 = square_blob(X, Y, 1, 1, 6, size=1)
data_13 = square_blob(X, Y, 4, 4, 6, size=1)

# Creating datasets
ds_12 = xr.DataArray(data_12, dims=['y', 'x'], coords={'x': x, 'y': y}).expand_dims(time=[np.datetime64("2024-01-01T12:00")])
ds_13 = xr.DataArray(data_13, dims=['y', 'x'], coords={'x': x, 'y': y}).expand_dims(time=[np.datetime64("2024-01-01T13:00")])

# Concatenate and interpolate
ds_concat = xr.concat([ds_12, ds_13], dim='time')

# Convert time to numeric values (seconds since epoch)
time_numeric = (ds_concat.time - np.datetime64('1970-01-01')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')

# Interpolate using the numeric time values, then convert back to datetime
time_interp = np.linspace(time_numeric[0], time_numeric[-1], 60)
time_interp_datetime = np.datetime64('1970-01-01') + (time_interp * np.timedelta64(1, 's')).astype('timedelta64[ns]')
ds_interp = ds_concat.interp(time=time_interp_datetime)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 5)

def animate(i):
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 5)
    data = ds_interp.isel(time=i)
    ax.contourf(data.x, data.y, data, levels=np.linspace(0, 6, 7), cmap='viridis')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(ds_interp.time), interval=50)
ani.save('animation.gif', writer='pillow')
plt.show()
```

[image: Animation with a smoother transition, cnaging the intensity at a point from 0 to 6 over time]